# Como buscar dados de outra entidade usando Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, orm

Tenho duas entidades uma Produto (id, id_categoria, nome)
e outra Categoria (id, nome), na entidade produto quero trazer o
nome da categoria pelo id_categoria da tabela produto.
Existe uma maneira de fazer isto com anotações?

Comment: Você está mapeando classes a tabelas usando o ORM? Por exemplo, uma classe Produto corresponde à tabela produto, assim como uma classe Categoria corresponderia à tabela categoria? Está usando mapeamento ManyToOne, OneToMany ou ManyToMany? Nos passe mais detalhes da sua implementação.

Comment: Sim é uma associação Many-to-one. Tem exemplo aqui: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html É em inglês, mas o exemplo é auto-explicativo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de reler a pergunta vi que é uma associação Many-To-One. Vamos lá então: você precisa criar duas classes – `Produto` e `Categoria` – e mapear os relacionamentos usando anotações. O relacionamento pode ser feito de diversas maneiras diferentes, sendo unidirecionais (a informação de relacionamento fica em apenas uma das entidades) ou bidirecionais (a informação de relacionamento fica em ambas as entidades). Pessoalmente prefiro essa última, que é a que vou usar para explicar seu caso.

Classe `Produto`:

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Produto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="produtos")
     */
    protected $categoria;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $nome;
}
```

class `Categoria`:

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Categoria
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Phone", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $produtos;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $nome;
}
```

Alguns pontos importantes:

- Prefiro usar relacionamentos bidirecionais em quase 100% dos casos pois dessa forma não preciso criar queries customizadas em DQL. Após gerar os *stubs* (os métodos das classes acima), é possível buscar a categoria de um produto com `$produto->getCategoria()`, da mesma forma que você busca os produtos de uma categoria com `$categoria->getProdutos()`.
- Apesar do atributo `$categoria` implicar na criação da coluna `categoria_id` na tabela de produtos, o mesmo não acontecerá porque você declarou o atributo `$produtos` na tabela de categoria; é apenas uma informação de relacionamento.
- No exemplo acima, a coluna `categoria_id` do `Produto` será nula, pois é padrão do Doctrine. Para que a coluna seja não-nula, basta adicionar a anotação `@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)` no atributo `$categoria`.